# Proving that $[0,1] \times X \cong [0,1] \times Y$, where $X$ is Möbius strip, $Y$ is curved surface of cylinder, and $\cong$ denotes homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, mobius-band

I want to prove that $[0,1] \times X \cong [0,1] \times Y$ where $[0,1] \subset \mathbb R$ has the usual Euclidean topology, $X$ is a Möbius strip and $Y$ is the curved surface of a cylinder. Here, $\cong$ denotes that there exists a homeomorphism between the two spaces.

I know how to express $X$ and $Y$ as quotient spaces of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ but I'm stuck on what to do next.

Comment: What does the identity on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ look like under these quotients?

Comment: Well, then you are out of luck since the first space is non-orientable and the second one is, which means that they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Wait, are you sure? Can't you just rotate?

Comment: Rotate what? It is a general fact that the product of a non-orientable manifold with another manifold is again non-orientable.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I mean rotate the map continuously as you go around the strip, so that the normal vectors line up

Comment: Is there a proof of that?

Comment: In the smooth setting see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550426/product-of-manifolds-orientability. One can also give a purely topological proof but it requires some knowledge of homology (Kunneth formula) on your part.

Comment: By $\simeq$ do you mean homotopy equivalent or homeomorphic? The spaces are homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  I mean homeomorphic. Is orientability preserved under homomorphisms?

Comment: @bwv869: Yes, orientability is preserved by homeomorphisms. Proving this is easy in the setting of smooth manifolds and diffeomorphisms and a bit more complicated in general (you need to know some homology theory). You can also see that the boundary of $[0,1]\times X$ is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle while the boundary of  $[0,1]\times Y$ is  homeomorphic to the torus, which are not homeomorphic (by comparing their fundamental groups). This is another way to prove that the two spaces are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above.*

---

Orientability is preserved under homeomorphisms and it is a general fact that if $X$ is non-orientable and $Y$ and $Z$ are orientable, then $Z \times X$ is non-orientable and $Z \times Y$ is orientable. In your case, we have $Z = [0,1]$, $X = $ Möbius strip and $Y = $ curved surface of cylinder. So,
$$
[0,1] \times X \not\cong [0,1] \times Y.
$$